Ubuntu 24.04 password not accepted after installation
Dears,
I've installed version 24.04 two times. both installations are ok, but when try to login it says the password is wrong. checked the password with shown input both times during installation and at login(s).
what's happening?
first time since 12.04 I have this problem.
Best,
Fabio

Check your caps lock. Try with a password that doesn't rely on a specific keyboard layout.

everything was checked: capslock, layout, password unhide. the password was input correctly in every stage from installation to first login. the only thing that worked was to enter in recovery mode and use passwd.

There is more wrong with 24.04 then all previous releases together, New kernel has some serious bugs. Maybe this is one too. Stick with 23.10 for now is my advice.
